# Get Html text input value into a Javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, user-input

I'm creating a countdown timer for a user selected time. For that I have developed following function.

```
function countdownTimeStart(){

var countDownDate = new Date("Sep 5, 2018 15:37:25").getTime();

var x = setInterval(function() {

    // Get to days date and time
    var now = new Date().getTime();

    // Find the distance between now an the count down date
    var distance = countDownDate - now;

    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
    document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = hours + ": "
        + minutes + ": " + seconds + " ";

    // If the count down is over, write some text
    if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
    }
}, 1000);
 }
```

This works fine. But I want to get a user selected value from a text input instead of `var countDownDate = new Date("Sep 5, 2018 15:37:25").getTime();`

Such as

```
<input type = "text" id = "picker-dates" value="08:30:20">
```

So can anyone help me to get this input value to my javascript function.

Comment: research `.value`

Comment: For what year/month/day? They are not defined in the element.

Comment: For hour,minutes and seconds

Comment: You may want to use *type="date"* or *type="datetime-local"* instead of *type="text"* – https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local

Comment: @ChathuriFernando was the answer helpful?

Comment: Checking the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First get the time value from the `input` using the `getElementById` and then split that value with colon `:` to get the hour, minutes and seconds. With these value you can use `setHours` in the current date to set the time specified in the `input`.

```js
function countdownTimeStart(){
var time = document.getElementById("picker-dates").value;
time = time.split(':');
var date = new Date();
var countDownDate = date.setHours(time[0],time[1],time[2]);
var x = setInterval(function() {
    // Get to days date and time
    var now = new Date().getTime();

    // Find the distance between now an the count down date
    var distance = countDownDate - now;

    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
    document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = hours + ": "
        + minutes + ": " + seconds + " ";

    // If the count down is over, write some text
    if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
    }
  }, 1000);
}
 
 countdownTimeStart();
```

```html
<input type = "text" id = "picker-dates" value="14:30:20">
<div id='demo1'></div>
```

Comment: The answer is very helpful, But there is a problem, the value 14:30:20. But the count start from another time. something like 6:42:20

Comment: Because @ChathuriFernando you are using the difference time for count down timer as in your code `var distance = countDownDate - now;` you can simply set the `distance` with the value of `countDownDate` as `var distance = countDownDate` to get started from the user input value.

Comment: Should I use var distance = countDownDate instead of var distance = countDownDate - now;  ?

Comment: @ChathuriFernando yes, If you want the timer to start from the input value

Comment: But then not countdown the time

Comment: Not working @Ankit Agarwal, please help me to solve it

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this, please have a look and if it doesn't work please let me know.

```
var selectedValue = document.getElementById("picker-dates").value;
```

Comment: @ChathuriFernando doing that much will not work. You need to add some more date operations to make it work

Comment: So can you please show the way for work my code since I'm new to the javascript

Comment: Here I'm not considering about the date or year, I just only need to count time for hour,minutes and seconds

Answer (score -1):

use jquery:  $('#picker-dates').val()

Comment: not everyone wants to use jquery - it's added mb to your site, as well as having to learn a slightly different syntax